# Mounted Gluster volume keeps reverting to "root" permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, glusterfs, directory, chown

Ive got GlusterFS running on an AWS server and its mounted to another AWS server. The folder that is mounted though keeps reverting to "root" ownership, when this happens uploads fail from the web browser as nginx is the owner trying to upload the file.

I manually change the folder back as being owned by nginx:nginx but for some reason, in time it'll always revert back to root:root and uploads will fail again.

Is there a way i can lock it and prevent root from reseting the permissions back?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameters

storage.owner.gid

storage.owner.uid


glusterfs 3.5.0 built on May  1 2014 11:57:24

Option: storage.owner-uid
Default Value: (null)
Description: Support for setting uid of brick's owner


Option: storage.owner-gid
Default Value: (null)
Description: Support for setting gid of brick's owner


Cheers.